# Why do some codes in Binary Search set the middle pivot as 'left + (right - left) //2'?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

For example, basic binary search in Python:

```
left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1

while left <= right:
    # // 2 -> floor
    pivot = left + (right - left) // 2
    if nums[pivot] == target:
        return pivot
    if target < nums[pivot]:
        right = pivot - 1
    else:
        left = pivot + 1
```

In this code, pivot is `left + (right - left) // 2`, not `len(nums) // 2`.
Could you explain why?

Comment: Does the algorithm still work if `len(nums) // 2` is used instead?

Comment: `len(nums)` is a constant, it will never change when `left` and/or `right` changes.

Comment: What I was going to ask was that I don't know why used the method as `left + (right - left) //2` when deciding on a pivot. Is there any advantage when choosing a pivot compared to `len(nums) // 2`?

Comment: Assume that `len(nums)` is `100` and `left=60`, `right=70`. In this case `len(nums) // 2` lies outside the range while `left + (right-left) // 2` is `65`; right in the middle as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len(sums)//2` is never interchangeable with `left + (right - left) // 2`. They are different things. But there is `(left + right) // 2` which may be what you are confused about.

`left + (right - left) // 2` and `(left + right) // 2` are basically the same except for one thing: The latter can overflow due to the fact that we first add `left` and `right` and then divide. Integer overflow is not possible in Python but this can happen in languages like C and Java where the size of an integer is limited.

[Read this article](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) about how this bug is prevalent in many code bases.